# TableView Collapse/Expand with sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Question related to UITableView collapse and Expand mode with dynamic sections. We got the requirement of showing the number of cells which has the collapse and expand option and once user expand the cell which will be having the list of sections and cells.
For more info I am attaching the screenshot, and please suggest me the best approach.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are several options how to do that:
1) For your expandable sections you have one cell , tapping on which you will insert/delete the needed number of options(cells) to your sections via `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:` / `-deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:`

2) Or place option cells directly in `-tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath` and set height = 0 for them(i.e. hidden options(cells). And when user taps the expandable 1st cell - call 
[tbl beginUpdates];
[tbl reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tbl endUpdates];

Comment: When your call the last method don't forget to change the hight from 0 to the correct value. So, 1st method is flexible and I'd recommend you to use it rather than option 2.

Comment: [this is the one I always use](http://sugartin.info/2011/07/20/447/)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of libraries available for this and many more other requirements,check out this [cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=expandable)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has made a demo, the key is to manipulate your section header, detail check this

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html